# Typing text not updated in the Textfield in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, hummingbird, flutter-text

I tried to create a flutter website. UI wise all work fine. In Textfield, when typed in the keyboard it wasn't updated in the Textfield.

**Code:**

```
 TextFormField(
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: widget.hint,
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(0.0),
        ),
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: HexColor(ColorCode.lightGrey),
          width: 1.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    onSaved: (String value) {
      print("=====>" + value);
    },
  )
```